# How do I combine four IF functions into one IF function

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010

How do I combine four IF functions into one IF function.

```
IF(C7+F7)>0,G7-(C7+F7),F7-G7)  
IF((C7+F7)>0,G7-(C7+F7),G7) 
IF(AND(C7<0,F7<0),G7,0) 
IF((C7+F7)<0,G7-(C7+F7),F7-G7)
```

Comment: You can't, because the first one does not compile, and if it did, it would be equivalent to the second one, so you'd have two different expressions returned in response to the same condition.

Comment: how about these three formulas. IF(AND(C7>0,F>0,G7,G7-(C7+F7) IF((C7+F7)>0,G7-(C7+F7),F7-G7) IF((C7+F7)<0,G7,G7-(C7+F7)

Comment: I know the second and third if function is the same, but the true and false value would be different under each circumstance

Comment: Why don't you start by testing each logical test individually so you understand what will happen?

Comment: I did that. Individually it gives me right answer. I just want to combine the formula so that I can run it for all the numbers in the list

Comment: `=IF((C7+F7)<>0,G7-(C7+F7), IF(AND(C7<0,F7<0),G7,F7-G7))`?  But it is difficult because the first two have the same logical test, but the false is different for both of them, so it is hard to follow your logic path as the false for the same test results in two different outcomes.

Comment: You said you tested... IF(AND(C7>0,F>0,G7,G7-(C7+F7) This fails at the first test as you did not close the bracket for the AND().

Comment: How to combine all four conditions and make one IF function

If C7<0,F7<0 should give G7

If C7>0,F7>0 should give G7-(C7+F7)

if (C7+F7)>0,C7<0 should give G7-(C7+F7)

if(C7+F7)<0,C7<0 should give G7-F7

if(C7+F7)>0,F7<0 should give G7-(C7+F7)

if(C7+F7)<0,F7<0 should give G7

IF function combining all conditions

Comment: I think these conditions are correct. Can someone help me with this

Comment: Try each individual condition in Excel, you will see some don't work. Fix them, then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75891871/edit) to include the correct `IF` statements and your attempt to combine them